# Pandas indexing by both boolean `loc` and subsequent `iloc`

Tags: python, pandas

I want to index a Pandas dataframe using a boolean mask, then set a value in a subset of the filtered dataframe based on an integer index, and have this value reflected in the dataframe. That is, I would be happy if this worked on a view of the dataframe.

Example:

```
In [293]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'b': [5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2],
                   'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

mask = (df['a'] < 7) & (df['b'] == 2)
df.loc[mask, 'c']

Out[293]:
2    0
3    0
6    0
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Now I would like to set the values of the first two elements returned in the filtered dataframe. Chaining an `iloc` onto the `loc` call above works to index:

```
In [294]:

df.loc[mask, 'c'].iloc[0: 2]

Out[294]:

2    0
3    0
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

But not to assign:

```
In [295]:

df.loc[mask, 'c'].iloc[0: 2] = 1

print(df)

   a  b  c
0  0  5  0
1  1  5  0
2  2  2  0
3  3  2  0
4  4  5  0
5  5  5  0
6  6  2  0
7  7  2  0
```

Making the assign value the same length as the slice (i.e. `= [1, 1]`) also doesn't work. Is there a way to assign these values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does work but is a little ugly, basically we use the index generated from the mask and make an additional call to `loc`:

```
In [57]:

df.loc[df.loc[mask,'c'].iloc[0:2].index, 'c'] = 1
df
Out[57]:
   a  b  c
0  0  5  0
1  1  5  0
2  2  2  1
3  3  2  1
4  4  5  0
5  5  5  0
6  6  2  0
7  7  2  0
```

So breaking the above down:

```
In [60]:
# take the index from the mask and iloc
df.loc[mask, 'c'].iloc[0: 2]
Out[60]:
2    0
3    0
Name: c, dtype: int64
In [61]:
# call loc using this index, we can now use this to select column 'c' and set the value
df.loc[df.loc[mask,'c'].iloc[0:2].index]
Out[61]:
   a  b  c
2  2  2  0
3  3  2  0
```

Comment: That works, thanks @EdChum. Perhaps someone comes up with something more elegant.

Comment: @tsawallis I hope so, this maybe one of those cases where you have to do this because the different indexing methods don't allow such complicated selection criteria and if you start chaining the indexing calls then they silently fail as you've found, this way there is no ambiguity and it will always work on a view

Answer (score 6):

How about.

```
ix = df.index[mask][:2]
df.loc[ix, 'c'] = 1
```

Same idea as EdChum but more elegant as suggested in the comment.

EDIT: Have to be a little bit careful with this one as it may give unwanted results with a non-unique index, since there could be multiple rows indexed by either of the label in `ix` above. If the index is non-unique and you only want the first 2 (or n) rows that satisfy the boolean key, it would be safer to use `.iloc` with integer indexing with something like

```
ix = np.where(mask)[0][:2]
df.iloc[ix, 'c'] = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is any more elegant, but it's a little different:

```
mask = mask & (mask.cumsum() < 3)

df.loc[mask, 'c'] = 1

   a  b  c
0  0  5  0
1  1  5  0
2  2  2  1
3  3  2  1
4  4  5  0
5  5  5  0
6  6  2  0
7  7  2  0
```